# Understanding the definition of $\tilde f$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The next next paragraph is from Qing Liu's "*Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*" p. 61. The definition of $\tilde f$ is unclear to me.

Here's the meaning of the notations. $k$ is a field, and $X$ is an algebraic variety over $k$. $\mathcal O_X$ is the sheaf given on $X$. $X^0$ is the topological subspace made up of the closed points of $X$. $k(x)$ is the residue field $\mathcal O_{X,x}/\mathfrak m_x$, where $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ is the stalk of $\mathcal O_X$ at $x$ and $\mathfrak m_x$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathcal O_{X,x}$.

[image]

Let's fix $x\in X^0$. Since $k(x)$ is an algebraic extension of $k$, there is an injective ring homomorphism $\varphi: k\to\bar k$. So $\tilde f(x) = \varphi(\text{the image of $f_x$ in $k(x)$})$. But what if there are two different injective ring homomorphisms $\varphi_1, \varphi_2: k\to\bar k$? How is $\tilde f(x)$ defined?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that all embeddings (including more problematic $k(x)\to\overline{k}$) are fixed as a part of "fix an algebraic closure" statement.

Comment: So you're saying that we should fix not just $\bar k$ but also maps $k(x)\to\bar k$ for each $x\in X^0$?

Comment: Yes, I think so.